# Facing this error : AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'DeprecationDict' on <module 'sklearn.utils.deprecation'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Facing this issue while running the code to load ML model pickle file.,, 
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'DeprecationDict' on

Comment: please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

You used a new version of scikit-learn to load a model that was trained by an older version of scikit-learn.

Therefore, the options are:

1. Retrain the model with the current version of scikit-learn if you have a training text and data.
2. Or go back to the lower version of the scikit-learn reported in the warning message